# How to identify overflow error with long?

Tags: java, overflow, long-integer, memoization

I am trying to use memoization to identify when overflow occurs: But the error is not being thrown (the Runtimeexception) so is still just outputting negative values as the result

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class combinations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner to take user input for n and k
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String[] input = sc.nextLine().split(" "); //takes the input line and separate it into the 2 numbers
            long n, k, one;
            one= 1;
            long[][] cache; //for bigger numbers that will lead to overflow
            if(input.length==2){ //assigns the input to variables n and k 
                try {
                    n = Long.parseLong(input[0]);
                    k = Long.parseLong(input[1]);
                    cache = new long[n + one][n + one];
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // exception allowed if the input is invalid, scanner remains open so they can try again 
                }  

                try{
                    System.out.println(binomialCoefficient(n, k, cache)); //calls function to compute the answer
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    //This method computes the mathematical equation
    public static long binomialCoefficient(long n, long k, long[][] cache) {  
        if (k == 0 || k == n) {
            return cache[n][k] = 1;
        } else if (cache[n][k] != 0) {
            return cache[n][k];
        } else {
            cache[n][k] = binomialCoefficient(n-1, k-1, cache) + binomialCoefficient(n-1, k, cache);
            if (cache[n][k] < 0) {
                System.out.println("error is caught");
                throw new RuntimeException("Overflow occured");
            }
            return cache[n][k];
        }

    }


}
```

Error message not outputting

Comment: Java integer arithmetic wraps around instead of throwing an overflow exception. If you need to detect overflow, use the `~Exact` methods in the [Math API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) .

Comment: Did you compile and run your code successfully?  `cache = new long[n + one][n + one];`, for this one, it looks impossible. In Java, array max size only could be Integer.

Please check your codes and make it run.

Comment: You said your code is outputting negative values as a result! But tried your exact source code in my Desktop IDE, and got the following error message:

`java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int`